Backfill Google Analytics (GA4) Data in Big Query
I enabled BigQuery export from Google Analytics GA4 yesterday, I understand that from now on I will get a daily export; which I confirm it works.
However, I am interested in exporting data from before I activated the link. This is data from a few days ago before (e.g., 2 days to be exact).
If it's not possible I am interested to know if there is another way to query the data.

firebaser here There is no backfill option for getting data from before you enabled the export.
